# Empty string passed to getElementByID()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, getelementbyid

I am trying use my script in order to open a pdf file by clicking a radio button, but my console shows me an error of ***Empty string passed to getElementByID()*** however, script fetched the correct file and code to display but it does not appear on the screen. I also attached the screenshot of my browser. Please guide me what can be the reason?

```
<label><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="view_ta" data-ta-id="" >
<input class="input-text" type="radio" style="width: 30px;" value="iagree" name="agreement"></a><span style="display: block; float: right; margin-top: 3px;">Я согласен с<!--I Agree With--></span></label>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.view_ta').click(function(){
            var jq = $(this);
            var ta_id = jq.attr('data-ta-id');
            var agrmnt_type = '';
            if(ta_id == ''){
                agrmnt_type == "RUNI";

            }
            $('.mod-agr-app').find('.modal-content').html('')
            $.post('/call_ajax.php',{holder:'show_agr',agrmnt_type:agrmnt_type,ta_id:ta_id},function(res){ 
                console.log(res);
                $('.mod-agr-app').find('.modal-content').html(res);
                $('.mod-agr-app').modal('show');
            });
        })

    });
    </script>[Please have a look the screenshot][1]
```